# using ismember and indexing to get values from one vector to another

Tags: matlab

I have 2 vectors of Ids, lets call them a_id (10000 x 1) & b_id (4500 x 1).

I also have a vectors of numerical values, lets calls it b_num (4500 x 1). The values in b_num correspond to the id's in b_id.

Lastly I have a vector lets call it a_num which is (10000 x 1) which has no values in it. I want to populate it with the values from b_num where the id's match in a_id and b_id.

```
a_id         b_id              b_num
ADA          BHN               2
PLB          ADA               4
BHN          LMK               3
LMK
```

So the result would look something like below,

```
a_id        a_num
ADA         4
PLB         0
BHN         2
LMK         3
```

I am trying to use ismember but with out much joy.

```
a_num = NaN * ones(length(a_id(:, 1)), 1);    

[found, pos] = ismember(a_id, b_id);

a_num(found(found~=0), 1) = b_num(pos(pos~=0), 1);
```

The result is

```
a_id        a_num
ADA         4
PLB         2
BHN         3
LMK         NaN
```

Comment: [`intersect`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html) is probably the more appropriate set operation

Comment: @excaza I'm not sure if that works though. I want a_num to have the same number of elements as a_id. Intersect would return a 3 x 1 I believe

Comment: are `a_id` & `b_id` cell arrays?

Comment: @AeroEngy yes they are

Comment: @AeroEngy the poster of a question gets notified when an answer is posted, no need for additional comments which do nothing but point them to your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?  `ismember` seems to work fine.  I think you were just miss using the `found` part of your code (`idxa` in mine).  That is a logical array so you did not need to do this  `found(found~=0)`

```
>> a_id  ={ 'ADA' 'PLB' 'BHN' 'LMK'};
>> b_id = {'BHN' 'ADA' 'LMK'};
>> b_num = [2 4 3];

>> [idxa idxb] = ismember(a_id,b_id)
idxa =
     1     0     1     1    
idxb =
     2     0     1     3

>> a_num = zeros(size(a_id));    
>> a_num(idxa) = b_num(idxb(idxb~=0))
a_num =

     4     0     2     3
```

Note: replace `zeros()` with `nan()` in the initialization of `a_num` if you prefer that instead.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you can use `NaN` with input arguments the same as `ones`, so initialise your `a_num` using

```
a_num = NaN(size(a_id)); % Use size instead of length for clarity. length(x) = max(size(x))
```

#### Getting `ismember` to work

We can find all indices of `a_id` within `b_id` and assign like so

```
[bfound, idx] = ismember(a_id, b_id); % Find a_id members in b_id
a_num(bfound) = b_num(idx(bfound));   % Assign matched values
% output [4 NaN 2 3]
```

---

#### Using `intersect`

You can avoid some logical indexing by using the index arguments of [`intersect`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html). After initialising `a_num` the same...

```
[~, a_idx, b_idx] = intersect(a_id, b_id); % indices of b in a and a in b
a_num(a_idx) = b_num(b_idx);
% output [4 NaN 2 3]
```